# Is it possible to go to the next field on tab button press?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to go to the next field on tab button press, if yes how can we do that.

Here I am using bootstrap classes `col-md-6`.

Thanks!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Travel Place</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="txtTravelPlace" type="text" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="txtTravelPlace">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Cost (Rs)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="txtCost" min="1" type="number" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="txtCost">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">To Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="dtToDate" type="date" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="dtToDate" min="2021-05-06">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Remarks</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <textarea class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="txtRemarks" rows="2" ng-reflect-name="txtRemarks"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything in your code to go to next field if you press `tab` button. It is working as you intended

Comment: Why do you think it's *not* working?  Have you tried it?

Comment: The function of focusing  to the next input field on tab key is the standard in all browsers. I reckon you want to change the order in which the input fields are focused, don't you?

Comment: On clicking `tab` it's working. But I want to go to right side text field. like `Travel Place` to `To Date` field. Because I am using this format to my entire bucket. So need this. Thank you for your quick response. *Please click Full Page view for understanding*

Comment: Don't put in unnecessary tags, this question is not related to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a new answer which focuses the relevant input elements in visual order (left to right, top to bottom)

Be aware that this may pose some accessibility (a11y) issues

```js
{
  "use strict";

  let inputs = [];

  // This is used to sort the inputs
  const factor = 1e6;
  // This selector is variable to the use case
  const inputSelector = ".form-group :is(input,select,textarea,button).form-control";

  // Calculates a positional value of an element which favors y position over x position
  const getInputPosition = input => (rect = input.getBoundingClientRect(), rect.y * factor + rect.x);
  const getInputs = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(inputSelector));
  // This sort might have a poor performance, if there are a lot of relevant form elements
  const sortInputs = () => getInputs().sort((a, b) => getInputPosition(a) - getInputPosition(b));
  const updateInputs = () => {
    inputs.forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown));
    inputs = sortInputs();
    inputs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown));
  };

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (!(e.keyCode && e.keyCode === 9)) return;

    const index = inputs.indexOf(e.target);
    if (index < 0) return;

    // By this modulo calculation we loop through the fields.
    // If you don't want that to happen, just use 
    // const nextIndex = index + 1
    const nextIndex = (index + 1) % inputs.length;
    if (!inputs[nextIndex]) return;

    inputs[nextIndex].focus();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateInputs);
  window.addEventListener("resize", updateInputs);
  
  // If you dynamically load form elements (e.g. by AJAX), uncomment these
  // const observer = new MutationObserver(updateInputs);
  // const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
  // observer.observe(document.documentElement, config);

  updateInputs();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Travel Place</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="txtTravelPlace" type="text" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="txtTravelPlace">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Cost (Rs)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="txtCost" min="1" type="number" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="txtCost">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">To Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="dtToDate" type="date" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="dtToDate" min="2021-05-06">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Remarks</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <textarea class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="txtRemarks" rows="2" ng-reflect-name="txtRemarks"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am tried this in my code, Not working.

Comment: Did you read the comments in my coffee and adjusted accordingly?

Comment: @ManojBalakonda What exactly isn't working. Do you have any code to look at?

Answer (score 1):

### Comment

This answer does not answer the question the asker did want to ask, but maybe it will provide insight for anyone else. My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415838/476951) will provide a JavaScript solution.

### Original answer

You shouldn't put your form-groups into column, but the form-group should themselves be columns. So I strapped the `<div class="col-md-6">` wrappers and added `col-md-6` class to every `form-group`.

For this to show in your original order I had to change the order from ABCD to ACBD

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Travel Place</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="txtTravelPlace" type="text" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="txtTravelPlace">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">To Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="dtToDate" type="date" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="dtToDate" min="2021-05-06">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Cost (Rs)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input class="form-control m-t-5 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="txtCost" min="1" type="number" ng-reflect-klass="form-control m-t-5" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="txtCost">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label star">Remarks</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <textarea class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="txtRemarks" rows="2" ng-reflect-name="txtRemarks"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Further explanation

What you did:

```
+-- .row -------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         |
| +-- .col-md-6 ------------+ +-- .col-md-6 ------------+ |
| |                         | |                         | |
| | +-- .form-group.row --+ | | +-- .form-group.row --+ | |
| | |                     | | | |                     | | |
| | | +-----------------+ | | | | +-----------------+ | | |
| | | | Input A         | | | | | | Input C         | | | |
| | | +-----------------+ | | | | +-----------------+ | | |
| | |                     | | | |                     | | |
| | +---------------------+ | | +---------------------+ | |
| |                         | |                         | |
| | +-- .form-group.row --+ | | +-- .form-group.row --+ | |
| | |                     | | | |                     | | |
| | | +-----------------+ | | | | +-----------------+ | | |
| | | | Input B         | | | | | | Input D         | | | |
| | | +-----------------+ | | | | +-----------------+ | | |
| | |                     | | | |                     | | |
| | +---------------------+ | | +---------------------+ | |
| |                         | |                         | |
| +-------------------------+ +-------------------------+ |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I did

```
+-- .row -----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                   |
| +-- .form-group.row.col-md-6 --+ +-- .form-group.row.col-md-6 --+ |
| | +--------------------------+ | | +--------------------------+ | |
| | | Input A                  | | | | Input C                  | | |
| | +--------------------------+ | | +--------------------------+ | |
| +------------------------------+ +------------------------------+ |
|                                                                   |
| +-- .form-group.row.col-md-6 --+ +-- .form-group.row.col-md-6 --+ |
| | +--------------------------+ | | +--------------------------+ | |
| | | Input B                  | | | | Input D                  | | |
| | +--------------------------+ | | +--------------------------+ | |
| +------------------------------+ +------------------------------+ |
|                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check and let you know bro.

Comment: yunzen, Thank you for your answer, A quick question: I am using my format for my entire project. There is so many forms - up to 1600+, Instead of this, Is there any jQuery function or JavaScript function for this to helps for me. Tq

Comment: There would be the possibility to use `tabindex` aatribute (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex). But this is extremely tricky to handle and nearly impossible to work right, if you happen to have multiple forms on any page. It is generally not recommended to use `tabindex`

Comment: On the other hand a JavaScript solution should take into account the screen position (top and left) of every form element. There are two possibilities I see. Add/Modify tabindex attributes to every form element on load/resize (and any DOM manipulation, if that is the case). Or make an input listener on tab press that calculates the next focusable form element on the fly. Both solutions would not be trivial, but doable.

Comment: Good you found your solution but could you please edit this question so it's not referenced as "go to next tab on tab press" but "how to change the order of columns with bootstrap" instead and can remove my answer?

Comment: @savageGoat Who do you mean? Me or Manoj?

Comment: @Manoj, the question is "go to the next field on tab button press?", hence my answer, wich will be referenced as that, but it's not what you are asking and can be missleading for other persons looking for a solution

Comment: @savageGoat I think that comment should go to the OP not to my answer

Comment: Yes, I realised the error and edited for @Manoj instead, sorry

Comment: @savageGoat but here is my main goal is on tab clicking not columns order, tq

Comment: "I reckon you want to change the order in which the input fields are focused, don't you?", stil, the anwser is apropriated to the question you asked so I guess keeping it is good thing for other users

Comment: @savageGoat Look at my new answer

Comment: That works too, even if the question deosn't ask the for an order change, you answer fits to the "tab button" question

Answer (score 1):

In input tag use attribute tabindex.

See the below given example.(run the snippet in full page mode)

```html
 <input type="text" name="" tabindex="1" id="">
 <input type="text" name="" tabindex="2" id="">
 <input type="text" name="" tabindex="3" id="">
 <input type="text" name="" tabindex="4" id="">
```

in first input i have set tabindex="1". So on first tab click first input is selected. similarly in second input i used tabindex="2" so on second tab click second input will be selected

Comment: Thank you for your response, This is useful for me.

Comment: Please be aware that using positive tabindex values poses strong accessibility issues that are hard to come by. When you start using tabindex you should ensure that interactive element needs such a tabindex value that is hard to manage. See also https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex